# Restore previous version of database in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2012, restore

I need your help on restoring previous version of database on SQL Server.

In last week I restored database 'A' in DEV server with it's production copy and didn't realize that this database 'A' in DEV was not backed up and there was some already development work going on which is lost now!

Is there anyway of restoring previous version of 'A' database in DEV server?

Any help or suggestion would be really great!

Thank you!

Comment: Does your storage team take server level backups or SAN snaps etc?

Comment: Not Sure! It's entire team who manages day to day incidents and possibly backup! I can ask them!

Comment: Give it a go - if they can restore the disk that the mdf file was on, you might have a shot.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance if the answer to all the below questions is NO

1. Was the database name exactly identical in Prod and Dev?
2. When restoring Database A on the Dev server, did you explicitly choose to move the data and the log files to the same path (and overwrite them) where the original dev Database A resided?
3. Did you drop database A on the Dev box before restoring from the prod backup?

If the answer to all the above questions is No, then there is a chance that your restore did not overwrite the original files of database A on the dev server.

When restoring a database from a backup that was taken on a different server/DB, SQL Server creates data and log files on the same path as that of the original database (in your case prod copy of database A) that the backup belongs to (unless explicitly mentioned in the MOVE clause of the RESTORE command). So if the path of the data and log files on Prod is different from the Dev box, then the restore operation will not overwrite the files unless you explicitly specify WITH MOVE 'filename' TO 'path' in the restore command along with the option REPLACE.

In this case, check the local drives on the dev server and see if the files of the original Database A are still there (assuming the path of the files on database A is different on the dev box than on the prod). If you succeeded in finding the orphan files, and you can attach them as a different database (eg: A_dev).

Answer (score 0):

If database is restored on dev server and database backup was not scheduled to run on the dev server meaning no backup file is available for previously running database then, there is no way you can recover the previous database.

You may possibly ask your development team to re-deploy the things again for SQL code. Possibly, this would be learning to scheduled backup on dev server also based on the required frequency(daily/weekly).

Comment: you are right, unfortunately no backup was done by developer ..and when I restored I wanted to restored with some different name but since PROD and DEV was the same name by default it took 'A' database and restored work in progress database. do you thin there will be some log files or something where we can retrieve important tables?

Comment: No there is no way to restore without a previous backup, or disk snapshot. Transaction log files do not work that way.

Answer (score 0):

> ... I restored database 'A' in DEV server with it's production copy ...

You now have Production data in a non-Production environment, an eventuality that *may or may not* be covered by your organisation's Privacy Notice and, therefore, *may or may not* place your company in breach of GDPR (or similar) *legislation*.
You *might* want to think about that.

However, more immediately ...

> ... didn't realize that this database 'A' in DEV was not backed up ...

Why do you have ***any*** database that is not backed up?
*Especially* one that has people actively working with it?

In an Ideal World, all of the [structural] changes made by the Developers should have been *scripted*, allowing those scripts to be redeployed / reapplied to the database, getting it back to where it was.
If the *Developers* are not responsible for making those changes, then whoever *is* responsible should have written them, allowing those scripts to be redeployed / reapplied to the database.
If the Developers' / Testers' Test Case Data has disappeared, then they should be able to recreate that as well (from, you've guessed it, yet more scripts).  After all, it's *their* Test Data, so it's *their* responsibility.

Sorry to say it, but this just proves the old adage:

> Any Data that you don't have [at least] *two copies* of is Data that you *don't care* about.